# How do I tell the compiler to add a function call to every single function compiled?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, g++

I remember reading about a way of telling visual studio to add a function call to every single function at compile time. It was handy if you wanted to roll your own poor man's profiler. But I can't remember how to do it, or what it was called. I'd like to do the same thing with g++. Does anyone know how to do this?

Edit: So it looks like the visual studio equivalent is to compile with /Gh and give a definition for _penter and _pexit functions. For g++, you should look up -finstrument-functions compiler option.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Profile your program?

Comment: Yep! I want to write my own profiler.

Comment: Visual C++ supports this via the **/Gh** and **/GH** options, that work with `_penter` and `_pexit` hooks that you can write.

Comment: That was it! _penter and _pexit! Perfect!

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: You should probably put that in an answer field next time. :P

Comment: @GManNickG:  I thought the question was asking how to do this in g++, and I didn't know the answer to that.  I just wanted to clarify how it is done in Visual C++, since there was some uncertainty about that.

Answer (score 7):

> "So it looks like the visual studio equivalent is to compile with /Gh and give a definition for _penter and _pexit functions. For g++, you should look up -finstrument-functions compiler option."